# change .live function to on in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

hello everyone I need your  help
if someone can please change for me in this script .live function to .on function

```
$("#osmile-area a").live('click',function(){
    $("#osmile-area").fadeOut(300);
    return false;   
});
```

I found some instructions about how to change .live to .on but I think I'm are making some mistakes so I need help some of you to change in this code .live to .on function

thank you

Answer (score 1):

1 Sample should be enough:

```
$(".ocmessage").live({mouseenter:function(){

});
```

Should become:

```
$(document).on("mouseenter", ".ocmessage", function() {

});
```

just replace "live" with on" and put as base selector $(document) because this contains the up-to-date document. second parameter is your former selector and you're done.

This should work for every of your functions.

Comment: If there is a non-changing ancestor element, closer to the elements in question, use that instead of `document` for efficiency.

Comment: Yea ok you can do that aswell. But you should use an ID to address the element to be sure you dont trigger the element wrong due to an accident of reusing the class or similar. However the difference in performance is minimal except when your website and DOM amount is really huge/complex.